# How to get current windows user login name in MVC4 with .net Framework4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have been trying to the get the current windows user name, but finally NO.
Below are the ways which I have tried but could not get the user name, Am getting empty value

1. STEP I have tried with

   ```
   string usr System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
   ```

   Got empty value
2. STEP Checked in my local ISS under Security and Enabled Windows Authentication
3. STEP in my project I have checked the radio button to use "Use Visual Studio" Development Server
4. STEP in my `web.config` file I have selected Form=Windows

   ```
   <authentication mode="Windows">
       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
   </authentication>
   ```
5. STEP: I have also tried with authorization

   ```
   <authentication mode="Windows" >
       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
   </authentication>
   <authorization>
       <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
   ```
6. STEP: I hosted in my development server and made a check of Anonymous Authenticate = Disable and Windows Authentication = Enable
7. STEP: Authorize (I have used this on top of controller)

   ```
   string str = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
   ```

   but got empty value

I have tried all these way to get the current user name but am getting empty value. I am trying to get it under controller. Is there a way to get this? Please advice.

Comment: But, you are able to login to your site through windows authentication, right?

Comment: yes, i can but through this MVC am facing issue with my project

Answer (score 6):

Set this in `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    ....
    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
        ....
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This enabled **Windows authentication** to get your Windows user name.

Next, if you're using Internet Explorer, you need to add "http://localhost" to the list of valid **intranet** sites (in IE `Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet > Sites > Advanced` and then add `http://localhost` to that list). This allows IE to pick up the current Windows user and launch your web site automatically, without prompting for the username/password again.

In your `HomeController`'s `Index` method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // get the currently logged on Windows user
    ViewBag.UserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    return View();
}
```

and then in your view:

```
<h3>Hello, @ViewBag.UserName !</h3>
```

That's it !

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: @marc_s : I just put a break point and moved my cursor on identity, and just expanded that by click + mark, there i can see Authentication type = " " and is Authenticated = false and name= " "

Comment: @marc_s : some where i remember Authentication type should come as NTLM, then only i can able to get the user name.. not sure even though

Comment: @marc_s any idea??

Comment: No - as I said - this **works** if your machine is member of a Windows domain - I just tested it on my own machine. Not sure why it doesn't work for you - I *suspect* your web isn't really properly set to accept Windows authentication ....

Comment: @marc_s : I just crated Sample ASP.net application there am able to get my user name if i use this the below code, but why its not works in MVC4?  string s = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

Comment: Hurrayyyyyyy... I got the solution finally...!!!!!!!!!!!! Here it is. Just Added the below line in  app settings in web.config file..                                                     <appSettings>                                                                                    <add key="EnableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
 </appSettings>